# How to calculate the percentage of non null columns in sql server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

How to calculate the percentage of non null columns in sql server?

Comment: Welcome to SO , @Shilan. Please read , it will be helpful for your next questions -> http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Answer (score 1):

If you meant "how many non-null values are there in my table in a certain column":

```
SELECT
  percentage=CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM your_table)=0
    THEN 
      NULL
    ELSE
      CAST((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM your_table WHERE your_column IS NOT NULL) AS FLOAT)/
      (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM your_table)
  END
```

If you meant globally how many non null columns there are in all tables in your sql server instance:

```
SELECT
  percentage=
  CAST((
    SELECT
      COUNT(*)
    FROM
      INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE
      IS_NULLABLE='NO'
  ) AS FLOAT)/
  (
    SELECT
      COUNT(*)
    FROM
      INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  )
```